# Best way of sending REST responses in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, response

What is the best way to send rest responses in spring boot? Also how should i manage sending status codes to do it properly?

Currently i do it using ResponseEntity but i doubt this is the most elegant way.

Sample code:

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity post(@Valid @RequestBody Item item, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ModelErrors(bindingResult), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(itemService.addItem(item), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

ModelErrors class extends a HashMap class and just fetches and wraps the BindingResult's error messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I think that returning `ResponseEntity` is going to be the best choice for a lot of cases. A little more readable way of doing it in my opinion is to use the handy status methods on `ResponseEntity` like this

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity post(@Valid @RequestBody Item item, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ModelErrors(bindingResult));
    }

    return ResponseEntity.created().body(itemService.addItem(item));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `status` method passing a `HttpStatus` or status code like this

```
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ModelErrors(bindingResult));
ResponseEntity.status(201).body(itemService.addItem(item));
```

---

Another option is to just return whatever type you'd like without using `ResponseEntity`, but this gives you a lot less control over the response and requires that you have the proper `MessageConverter` configuration (you can read up on that [here](https://dzone.com/articles/customizing)).

A simple example might look like this

```
@RequestMapping("/hotdog")
public Hotdog hotdog() {
    return new Hotdog("mystery meat", "ketchup, mustard");
}
```

and if everything is configured correctly you'd end up with a response like this

```
{
    "content": "mystery meat",
    "condiments": "ketchup, mustard"
}
```

Comment: Didn't even know i could do that xd. Thanks. So the ResponseEntity isn't a bad way of sending responses? Is there a more popular way of doing that?

Comment: I think `ResponseEntity` is the way to go. I have updated my answer with another option.